# ASP.net MVC2 PartialView displays checkbox for only first item in the model list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on ASP.net MVC 2 web application, I am using a partial view to generate a list. The partial view code looks like following...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Collections.Generic.List<DataAccessLayer.Entities.Recipient>>" %>
<%
    foreach (DataAccessLayer.Entities.Recipient oRecipient in Model)
    {
%>
<tr>
    <td width="10%" align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="recipientCheck" />
    </td>
    <td width="50%" align="left">
        <%: oRecipient.LastName%> <%: oRecipient.FirstName%>
    </td>
    <td width="40%">
        <%: oRecipient.RecipientEmail%>
        <%: oRecipient.RecipientPhone%>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

This partial view is integrated in a main view like...

```
<table id="recipientsTable">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("RecipientPartialView", Model.StaticClientContacts); %>
</table>
```

The PROBLEM is it is showing the checkbox only for the first item in the list, if I do firebug or view source it shows that the checkboxes are getting generated. 
Am I doing anything completely wrong here, anybody has any suggestions?

Comment: To clarify - is the problem a table row is displayed for each item in the model but a checkbox is only displayed for the first row?

Comment: Yes, table row and other text is shown/repeated properly but the checkbox is displayed only for the first row

Comment: If the markup for the checkboxes appears in the source after rendering the page is it possible you have some CSS or JavaScript which is applying styling or attributes to hide the other checkboxes?

Comment: If there is any parent style, how will it only affect all other checkboxes but not the first one?

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers TonE, I figured out the problem, some parent style was setting the field position to absolute so it was putting all the checkboxes at the same position. Although the answer is very specific to a very unique case, can you post your second comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the markup for the checkboxes appears in the source after rendering the page I would suspect some CSS or JavaScript is applying styling or attributes to hide the other checkboxes.